# how to access data values in success callback sent as parameter to jquery post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I have the following code

```
 function myfunc()
 {
 $.post(
 "http://www.crossdomain.com/",
 {code:'123'},
 function(data)
 {
 //use code value here 
 },
 'jsonp' 

 );

 }
```

1. cannot use $.ajax
2. cannot use global variable as value will constantly change
3. can additional parameter be passed to success function ?
4. can we use this keyword to access code value some how ?

Comment: He He Lot of conditions!!:)

Comment: Could you provide a better example? It's unclear to me what you want to access where.

Comment: _"cannot use $.ajax"_ - Why ever not?

Comment: @FelixKling ,the data passed to post call is to be accessed in the success callback function

Comment: @nnnnnn ajax have trouble with crossdomain,yql will not always work perfectly. so post call only and that is why the question arises ,other wise it is easily done in ajax.

Comment: But `$.post()` is just a shortcut to `$.ajax()` - it can't do anything `$.ajax()` can't do, it is _more_ restrictive... (I'm not saying you _need_ to use `$.ajax()`, I'm just saying your reason for ruling it out doesn't make sense.)

Comment: may be you re right but getjson and post work easily with cross domain where as ajax throws exception 0 even if you use datatype:jsonp , it happened to me,dont know about others but i think it will be a new question as for why or why not it works .

Comment: @nnnnnn made it work with ajax too :) .. but this was good to know too

Comment: The interesting part is that you actually can't make a JSONP POST request. JSONP is always GET. So I wonder was jQuery does in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding 3 and 4 - no. But this should work.

```
function myfunc()
{
    var params = {code:'123'};
    $.post(
        "http://www.crossdomain.com/",
        params,
        function(data)
        {
            alert("You have passed " + params.code);
        },
        'jsonp' 
    );
}
```

Here is complete working example, can be executed in jsfiddle:

```
var myFunc = function(codeVal)
{
    var params = {text: codeVal};
    $.post(
        "http://md5.jsontest.com/",
        params,
        function(data)
        {
            console.log("MD5(" + params.text + ") = " + data.md5);
        },
        'jsonp' 
    );
}

for (var i=1; i<5; ++i) {
    myFunc(i);
}
```

Comment: hey , params is outside post call , if i run it in a loop and params value changes, will it still use the value passed to post call with its respective loop ?

Comment: to use params value, you can call myFunc in a loop, passing to it parameters you need. Otherwise, yes, params will be overwritten at each iteration. But if you call myFunc in a loop, `params` will be local variable and will be preserved until request callback finish.